# The difference between 愚かな and 愚かしい

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

As far as I can tell, both mean foolish. Checking a dictionary, 愚かしい is defined as 愚かである。ばかげている。which does not help very much. Is there truly no real difference?

Comment: This page might be of some help... http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/3100/meaning/m0u/ `[使い分け]
「愚かしい」は、ばかげているさまの意でも用いられる。`

Answer (score 2):

The two words are similar in meaning and usage. However, two significant differences stand out.

1. 愚{おろ}かしい is much less commonly used than 愚{おろ}かな.
2. 愚かしい is virtually never used to refer to people, whereas 愚かな certainly can.

Comment: "愚かしい" is an old-fashioned phrase.

Comment: `愚かしい is virtually never used to refer to people` -> But... [this dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/3100/meaning/m0u/) gives an example sentence 「何と愚かしい人間だ」... あと「愚かしい男」「愚かしい自分」「愚かしいやつ」などをググるといくらかヒットしますが

Comment: Google search with quotes for exact matches: 愚かな人 has over _400 times_ as many results as 愚かしい人. 愚かな男 results in 320 times as many hits. 人間 results in 80 times as many hits. 者 yields 40 times as many results. I consider that to be rare usage.

Comment: (1) Google search doesn't quantify precisely ... so don't depend on that.

Comment: (2) `similar in meaning and usage` doesn't make any sense when one is `much less commonly used`.

Answer (score 2):

愚か（だ） describes the *quality* of "absent of wiseness", while 愚かしい, as with [many i-adjectives that end in -しい](http://dict4lyrics.from.tv/?q=%E3%81%97%E3%81%84&t=1), indicates a kind of *mental perception* such as sense, emotion or impression. In this sense, 愚かしい is actually telling "felt unwise" or "as if the unwise do", which is interestingly close to English approach to say *foolish* that is *fool* + *-ish*.

Thus you can say these two has slightly different connotation when both are usable:

> 戦争の愚かさ
>   (emphasizes how nonsense of (people to do) wars)
>
> 戦争の愚かしさ
>   (emphasizes how (people doing) wars look irrational)

And it's not totally impossible to find some examples only either one sounds valid:

> ○ 愚かな人間には理解できない *foolish humans will not understand*
>   × 愚かしい人間には理解できない

The latter is unacceptable because 愚かしい does not imply inherent, permanent character of foolishness.